# Draw a vertical band at the maximum value of a single-stream streamgraph in d3js that respects the bounds of curve?

Tags: d3.js, observable, data-visualization, stream-graph

Question: how do we draw a vertical band at the maximum value of a single-stream streamgraph in d3js that respects the bounds of curve?

[editable streamgraph example.](https://beta.observablehq.com/@blehman/untitled/2)

Imagine this is the original streamgraph:
[image: Streamgraph sans vertical band]
The question is focused on how we create something like this:
[image: Streamgraph with vertical band]

Comment: https://beta.observablehq.com/@gerardofurtado/inspiring-confidence

Comment: @GerardoFurtado - thanks! I don't think your line observes the boundaries of the curve though, right? I'm thinking about using a clip path to avoid this problem.

Comment: I'm not sure why you said that, it does respect the boundaries of the curve. Here is a zoom of it: https://imgur.com/a/U9ZcTtX. Of course, the line is adimensional for the width (I'm using 1px because that's the minimum possible). If you want a thicker line you won't have a line anymore, but a **path**, whose ends are curves. That's way more complicated. If you go for the clip path solution, which is simpler, you don't need to calculate the Y positions anymore, just start from `0` to `height` and the clip path does all the job.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado - You're spot on with your comment here. Just trying to solve for any line thickness (ie. ends are curved to respect the boundaries of the streamgraph)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following solution uses @GerardoFurtado's initial idea, but adds a clipPath to respect the bounds of the curve for any bandwidth:

https://beta.observablehq.com/@blehman/untitled/2